# Script run with shebang does not resolve aliases, how to circumvent?

Tags: bash, zsh, docker, windows-subsystem-for-linux, docker-for-windows

My main shell is `zsh`.

I am using Docker for Windows and therefore `docker` inside WSL is not found, because the call should be to `docker.exe`.

A quick hack I found online was to `alias docker=docker.exe`, which I did (for both: `.zshrc` & `.bashrc`), and with that, my CLI calls work.

Though, I have a script that starts with a `#!/usr/bin/env bash` and contains calls to `docker`.

Apparently that one doesn't pick the alias up, no matter if I run with `bash script.sh` or `./script.sh`, resulting in:

```
./script.sh: line 20: docker: command not found
```

Is there a way to circumvent this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Non-interactive `bash` won't expand aliases even if your script defines them (defines directly or by sourcing another file, explicitly or not); unless `shopt -s expand_aliases`.

I don't know `zsh` but I think this is irrelevant. Aliases are fine in your daily command line routine but in general they are not meant to be used in scripts. You should solve the problem without them in a shell-agnostic way.

I don't know WSL either. The following methods are quite basic in Linux, they should work.

1. A symlink:

   ```
   ln -s "/full/path/to/docker.exe" "/some/dir/in/your/PATH/docker"
   ```

   This way you will be able to run `docker.exe` under the name `docker` in (or even without) *any* shell. One disadvantage: if `docker.exe` is moved to another location then the symlink will stop working. You will need to remove it and recreate with the new path to `docker.exe`.
2. A wrapper script:

   ```
   #!/bin/sh
   # adjust the shebang if needed
   exec docker.exe "$@"
   ```

   Save it as `docker` in some directory in `PATH`; make the file executable. Now if you run `docker`, the script will `exec` to `docker.exe`. Again, calling `docker` will work in *any* shell, if only your `PATH` variable leads to `docker` and `docker.exe`.

Aliases are often used to "inject" an option (or options). Although this is not your case, let's make the answer more general. Consider `alias ll='ls -l'`. You cannot create a symlink that does this. You can however make a script, the relevant line would be:

```
exec ls -l "$@"
```

Comment: Oh, thanks! Got confused in all the interactive/non-interactive jazz. Makes sense why it doesn't work, and yeah, `zsh` / `WSL` is irrelevant here.

Comment: This is a good answer.  I am not sure if a symlink will work for this with WSL, because windows file system does not support symlinks.  The docker.exe is definitely on the windows file system.  I think the WSL is on the same file system too. EDIT: symlinks are spoofed as files, but they don't work.

Answer (score 2):

Your `.bashrc` or whatever file your setup uses should have a line like this: `[[ $- != *i* ]] && return` which will abort sourcing the resource file if it isn't an interactive shell. Thus your aliases are not sourced, because they are for interactive convenience.

To use an alias in you shell script you need to source a file of aliases or define the alias in the script.
Ultimately, it will be more lines of code to do this, and you are better off just calling the `.exe` file directly in the script.

NB. We really shouldn't source an alias file or our `.bashrc` into a script, because they are likely to change.

I hope this helps. Please let me know if you have any other questions.

Answer (score 0):

To make this possible, you can add those lines at the begining of your script.

```
. ~/.bashrc # or whatever file that contains aliases defs.
shopt -s expand_aliases
```

Then you can use your alias as a command

Same restriction for functions, you will need to do that in the parent shell.

```
export -f functionName
```

Keep in mind that is all for portability, people wont have your aliases and functions.